# Uv unwrapping giving lots of extra lines?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

[image: screenshot of problem]

So I am a complete beginner to blender and started trying to do this frog model tutorial. I got to the uv unwrapping after marking seams and have a mess instead of what the video showed. I have tried to look around and find a solution but I still have this problem and have no idea what I should do. Does anyone have a solution or suggestions that might help?

Comment: the model has horrible topology and most likely duplicate vertices causing this problem. you have to fix your topology first. research about good topology first and fix it. once your topology is good, then you can proceed with UV unwrapping.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: the easiest way to do some cleanup by going into Edit Mode (like in your screenshot) and selecting all vertices with "A" then pressing "M", then choose "By Distance" and you can adjust the threshold distance from 0.0001m to something else maybe 0.001m or 0.01m in the lower left corner